# Starting a Kafka consumer from a point where a different consumer left off

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have this issue am trying to figure out. Am upgrading an elasticsearch cluster currently and, we currently have create/update/delete requests piped through a Kafka queue. Let's assume consumer group A subscribes to these requests. I want to be able to pause consumer group A, spin up consumer group B and have consumer group A and B resume from where A left off.

Basically, A and B would both get copies of data from the queue from the point where A got paused previously. Would this be possible with Kafka ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have group B begin consuming from the same producer and have a little bit of overlap? It seems like attempting to pick up from A would overcomplicate things.

Comment: The problem is, the degree of overlap is not adjustable. The 2 options we have are I believe to consume starting from tip of queue or beginning of queue. If B starts consuming from the beginning, there would be an overlap but that overlap could potentially be weeks worth of messages.

Comment: I see. It's possible to implement your own functionality to choose an offset given a timestamp. In Kafka 0.10 its much easier with https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-32+-+Add+timestamps+to+Kafka+message. But if you are on an earlier version its not too difficult to run a service that will maintain a mapping of timestamp to offset. I supposed you could also create a producer to produce from Consumer A and have Consumer B consume from that producer.